# Drawing a graph using jlabel / jpanel

Tags: java, swing, alignment, jlabel

i'm building an algorithm visualizer using java swing and i want to set the height of the jlabel to a certain element

```
int arr[]={6,3,2,13,4};
then
JLabel1.setSize(10, arr[0]*5);
JLabel2.setSize(10, arr[1]*5);
JLabel3.setSize(10, arr[2]*5);
JLabel4.setSize(10, arr[3]*5);
JLabel5.setSize(10, arr[4]*5);
```

but when i set the sizes, the labels expanded to bottom making an inverted bar chart. how can i increase height while preserving the bottom alignment of jLabels ?

[The output after setting the values to jlabel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tN1wq.png)

source code for setting values

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
      abc = new JLabel[]{one,two,three,four,five}; //JlabelArray

      int p = Integer.parseInt(abc[0].getText());
      int q = Integer.parseInt(abc[1].getText());
      int r = Integer.parseInt(abc[2].getText());
      int s = Integer.parseInt(abc[3].getText());
      int t = Integer.parseInt(abc[4].getText());



      one.setSize(20, p*10 );
      one.setBackground(Color.decode("#03A9F4"));
      two.setSize(20, q*10 );
      two.setBackground(Color.decode("#03A9F4"));
      three.setSize(20, r*10 );
      three.setBackground(Color.decode("#03A9F4"));
      four.setSize(20, s*10 );
      four.setBackground(Color.decode("#03A9F4"));
      five.setSize(20, t*10 );
      five.setBackground(Color.decode("#03A9F4"));

      arr = new int[]{p,q,r,s,t}; //number array to be sorted

    }
```

*summery*
**Q: When i setSize of a jLabel, normally it grows towards bottom. How can i increase the height in positive y direction ?**

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Provide ASCII art or a simple drawing of the *intended* layout of the GUI at minimum size, and if resizable, with more width and height.

Comment: Please also post the part of your code that determines the location of the labels .

Comment: `Draw a Graph` Not sure if using separate Components such as this is the best approach - consider using a single JPanel and use [custom painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/). Alternatively use a graph library (such as [JFreeChart](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/))

Comment: @Berger *"Please **also** post the **part of your code..**"* By definition, an MCVE includes **all** the necessary parts for us to compile it and see the problem, so there is really no 'also' about it.

Comment: @copeg I'm going to sort (animate )the jlabels after assigning values. so jfreecharts is not an option

Comment: @rama41222 `I'm going to sort (animate )` Even more incentive to look into the custom painting option.

Answer (score 1):

Use a different layout manager on the panel you are adding the JLabels to - I'd suggest GridBagLayout.  It's a pain to get it right, but once you understand it it's pretty flexible for laying out components.  For your's I'd try:

```
JPanel pane = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());

GridBagConstants c = new GridBagConstants;

c.gridheight = REMAINDER;
c.gridwidth  = 1;
c.fill       = NONE;
c.anchor     = SOUTHWEST;
c.weightx    = 1;
c.weighty    = 0;

pane.add(label1, c);
pane.add(label2, c);
pane.add(label3, c);

c.gridwidth = RELATIVE;

pane.add(label4, c);

c.gridwidth = REMAINDER;

pane.add(label5, c);
```

Answer (score -1):

Another option besides a different LayoutManager is no LayoutManager at all (`JPanel.setLayout(null)`). In this way, any child components of the panel are not resized / moved around automatically, and you must position and size them yourself. This works well for fixed-size containers. Such a solution will look something like:

```
pane.setLayout(null);

pane.add(label1);
label1.setBounds(label1X, label1Y, label1Width, label1Height);
```

Please note that this also means that the components do not respond to size changes of their container - if that is required, a (possibly custom) LayoutManager is the better option.

Comment: *"Another option besides a different LayoutManager is no LayoutManager at all .."* Sure it's an option, but not one you should suggest to newbies. Please stop offering layout advice until you understand why. By the time the newbie has enough skill to layout a GUI, they can typically put that logic in a custom layout manager.